# Receiving image through sockets on androidstudio

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have written a code on Android Studio to receive images from a socket server and the application connects to the server every time a button is clicked.

However, when I run the app and click the button nothing shows up but the server sends a message saying the photo is sent. When I click the button again, for the second time (the server is not connected) the image pops up instantly.

I think the issue is that the thread isn't shutting down completely when I click the button once but if I click it again, the thread shuts down forcefully and starts a new one so the image is shown.

The code for the main activity java file is :

```
    package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;




public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTextViewReplyFromServer;
    private EditText mEditTextSendMessage;
    private ImageView mImg;
    private byte [] imgbyte;
    Handler updateConversationHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        mEditTextSendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_send_message);
        mTextViewReplyFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reply_from_server);
        mImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String filepath = "/sdcard/DCIM/img.jpeg";




    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.btn_send:
                Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
                fst.start();
                break;
        }
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        byte [] line;
        Bitmap bitmap;
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.145", 5560);
                        while (true) {
                            // LISTEN FOR INCOMING CLIENTS
                            try {
                                int bytesRead;
                                int current = 0;
                                int filesize=215320;
                                byte [] mybytearray2  = new byte [filesize];
                                InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/img.jpg"); // destination path and name of file
                                //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/");
                                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray2,0,mybytearray2.length);
                                current = bytesRead;


                                do {
                                    bytesRead =
                                            is.read(mybytearray2, current, (mybytearray2.length-current));
                                    if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                                } while(bytesRead > -1);

                                bos.write(mybytearray2, 0 , current);
                                bos.flush();
                               // bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mybytearray2 , 0, mybytearray2.length);
                               // mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                                //System.out.println(end-start);
                                updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(mybytearray2));
                                bos.close();
                                client.close();



                                break;
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
    class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
        private byte[] byteArray;//private String msg;

        public updateUIThread(byte[] array){    //public updateUIThread(String str) {
            this.byteArray=array;   //this.msg = str;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
            mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
        }
    }
    }
```

Is there anyway I can kill the thread immediately after the image is recieved?

My image also shows up on the android emulator but does not show up on my phone. What could be the reason for this?

Edit : if i start the thread on the oncreate section, the image pops up as soon as the application is started

Edit : python server code :

```
import socket
from time import sleep
from time import time

host = ''
port = 5560

filePath = "/media/pi/ESD-USB/image.jpg"

def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created.")
    try:
        s.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    print("Socket bind comlete.")
    return s

def setupConnection():
    s.listen(1) # Allows one connection at a time.
    conn, address = s.accept()
    print("Connected to: " + address[0] + ":" + str(address[1]))
    return conn

def sendPic(s, filePath):
    print(filePath)
    pic = open(filePath, 'rb')
    chunk = pic.read()
    size = len(chunk)
    print (size)
    t = time()
    print("Sending Picture")
    s.sendall(chunk)
    pic.close()
    print("Done sending")
    print("Elapsed time = " + str(time() - t) + 's')
    s.close()
    return "Done sending"



def backup(filePath):
    conn = setupConnection()
    response = sendPic(conn, filePath)
    return response


        

s = setupServer()


while True:
    print(filePath)
    backup(filePath)
    print("Everything should be backed up now.")
    break
```

Comment: `to receive images from a socket server` AND `the server sends a message saying the photo is received` do not match.

Comment: @blackapps my bad, the server says the photo has been sent.

Comment: `but the server sends a message saying the photo is sent.` To whom is the server sending that message? To your client? Where is the code to receive that message?

Comment: `mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` One cannot set the ui in the run() of a thread.

Comment: Why are you using a handler and a runnable to print stack traces? Makes no sense. Just print them.

Comment: @blackapps the server prints a message saying the image has been sent on the server side, ill edit my original post to add the code for the server now sorry

Comment: @blackapps i got this off a sample code and made a few changes to suit my use, i will remove them now, thank you for the suggestion! however, i dont think the problem is from the server end because once i click the button twice, the image displays immediately

Comment: @blackapps i edited my client code on the original post and now im not even getting the image the second time i click the button, really stuck here :(

Comment: `int filesize=215320;` ? Please explain. You will not know a file size at fore hand i assume.

Comment: `but the server sends a message saying the photo is sent. ` Can you edit that. The server is not sending such a message.

Comment: `class updateUIThread` No. You cannot update the ui in a thread. Use runOnUiThread instead. `updateConversationHandler.post` remove that handler.

Comment: @blackapps i had used length(chunk) in sendPic() function (server side) to find the length of the entire file and then i put it in the android studio code, is that wrong? and in the same sendPic() function once the operation is done, the server prints "Done sending". where would i place the runonuithread?

Comment: `public class ServerThread` Well.. that would br a client thread isnt it?

Comment: @blackapps you are right, there are a few typos and misnaming classes/threads in the code because i used a sample code and edited it to my use

Comment: Yes it is wrong to mess around with the length of the file. You dont need that. You did not tell it but after the server sent a picture the socket is closed. Thus the client can just read from the stream until -1 is returned. Just save the received bytes to file and check if the received file has same size as original. Forget the bitmap until you can receive the file. You better set the image in the imageview loading it from file .

Comment: @blackapps i understand what you mean. Do i send the filesize from python to the java code? if i send the size from python it will be sent in the form of bytes and is there any way to decode that to get an integer?

Comment: @blackapps i solved the problem, i removed the while loop and implemented the runonuithread like you mentioned. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what to do. the while loop was causing an issue and i implemented runonui thread like blackapps suggested.

The working code is shown below :

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTextViewReplyFromServer;
    private EditText mEditTextSendMessage;
    private ImageView mImg;
    private byte [] imgbyte;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        mEditTextSendMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_send_message);
        mTextViewReplyFromServer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_reply_from_server);
        mImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String filepath = "/sdcard/DCIM/img.jpeg";



    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Thread fst = new Thread(new ServerThread());
        fst.start();
    }

    public class ServerThread implements Runnable {
        byte [] line;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket client = new Socket("192.168.1.145", 5560);
                    try {
                        int bytesRead;
                        int current = 0;
                        int filesize = 300000;
                        byte [] mybytearray2  = new byte [filesize];
                        InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
                        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/DCIM/img.jpg"); // destination path and name of file
                        //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Screenshots/");
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                        bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray2,0,mybytearray2.length);
                        current = bytesRead;


                        do {
                            bytesRead =
                                    is.read(mybytearray2, current, (mybytearray2.length-current));
                            if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                        } while(bytesRead > -1);

                        bos.write(mybytearray2, 0 , current);
                        bos.flush();
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mybytearray2 , 0, mybytearray2.length);
                        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                mImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                            }
                        });
                        bos.close();
                        client.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the next step for me is to send the filesize of the image from the python server to the android app. also to figure out why my image does not show up on the an actual android but on the emulator.

Comment: Please.. no handlers and runnables to print a stack trace.